# Max initial zIndex for Google Maps V3 markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, z-index, google-maps-markers

I'm building a google maps web site with markers placed onto the map. Some times the markers overlap so I want to be able to interactively bring to the front specific markers.

I can use setZIndex() for this. But I need to know the initial max zindex of all the markers. getZIndex() is no use as it doesnt seem to return anything unless youve already called setZIndex().

It would be tempting to say "just start with a very big number" but I believe Google uses latitude or something to calculate the initial zIndex so the maximum zindex may vary? Making this scheme risky.

Does anyone know what the max initial zIndex will be for N markers in Google Maps V3?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the constant **MAX_ZINDEX** to ensure that the marker will display on top.

```
marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

Search the reference of the constant in the [Google Maps API V3 Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html)

Comment: For the lazy, the value is `1000000`

Comment: I had to set optimized to false for this work work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845916/google-maps-marker-zindex-doesnt-work-for-two-icon-types-symbol-and-string