# google.maps.Marker zIndex doesn't work for two icon types - Symbol and String

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When I add more Markers to Google Map with different icon types like:

```
...
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: markerLatLng,
             map: map,
             icon: "http://www.test.com/marker.png",
             zIndex: 10
         });
...
```

and

```
...
var resultIcon = {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            fillColor: "black",
            strokeColor: "black",
            strokeWeight: 1,
         };

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: markerLatLng,
             map: map,
             icon: resultIcon,
             zIndex: 5
         });
...
```

Than the zIndex doesn't work and the Symbol marker appears on the top.

Am I wrong with my code or how can I make the zIndex working?

Comment: Is your application working correctly when you don't specify custom icons?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to both specify a `zIndex` and add

```
optimized: false
```

to **every** marker constructor, eg.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: resultIcon,
    optimized: false,
    zIndex: 5
})
```

This seems to be an issue with the new canvas based rendering of the markers.

**Edit:**

This really solves the issue.
One thing to mention though is that every marker has to have the "optimized: false" attribute. As long as one marker does not have it, it will not work.

Remove any of the "optimized: false" attributes from LeJared's fiddle and you will encounter the bug.

http://jsfiddle.net/BNWYq/1/

Comment: You just saved me untold hours of pulling my hair out.

Comment: Worked for me!  However, its work reading the docs for optimized: "Optimization renders many markers as a single static element. Optimized rendering is enabled by default. Disable optimized rendering for animated GIFs or PNGs, or when each marker must be rendered as a separate DOM element (advanced usage only)."  (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Comment: Is there any way to set optimized to `false` with markerClusterer? My cluster markers are appearing over my 'You Are Here' marker regardless of the z-index of the 'You Are Here' marker.

Comment: Thank you!  This was absurdly hard to figure out.

Answer (score 9):

Setting zIndex of the circle to -99 seems to help: http://jsfiddle.net/rq4vs/2/

Comment: Hey, thats a nice solution, too. Thanks for correcting the fiddl.

Comment: Beware: The problem with this solution is that the symbol "steals" events like mouseover and click from the image, even though it is visually drawn underneath the image. Check this fiddle to see how the tooltip from the circle is shown instead of the pin tooltip, even if the circle is placed under the pin: http://jsfiddle.net/AEePr/ 

I hope google will solve this in a good way, because setting optimized=false is not ideal in all cases either.

Comment: -99 or whatever number of markers you have, safer to add -9999

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little fiddl:
http://jsfiddle.net/gSRmV/

Looks like a bug, that has to be fixed by google.

<strike>Adding `optimized: false` doesn't change anything.</strike>

**Edit:** Still looks like bug, but the two solutions from tborychowski and Codetoffel seem to work.